# Why isn't my new pressure tank filling?

Tags: pump, well, pressure

I replaced the pressure tank as the old one wouldn’t hold air. The new one was changed to 38 lbs. so I lowered it to 28 to match the power controller of 30/50.

There was low pressure before I change out the old tank which I assumed was the cause of the low pressure. I still have low pressure after turning the well back on. I have water to the outside faucets. The pressure gauge shows 32 psi and the well never shuts off.

What I don’t understand is why the new tank is not filling. Can anyone tell me what type of pump this is? I assume that I pull the motor off to get to the impeller.

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer, but your pump is probably worn out and needs to be replaced.  I suppose you could trying dissembling it and figuring out what's wrong and assuming you could get the needed parts, repair it.  But IMHO it looks like it's at the end of it's useful life.

Comment: Can you get to the impeller from the other side of the pump?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson   Hi George.

Comment: Depending on where you're at, you could have it tested and rebuilt if needed. You'd need a motor and pump repair shop.

Comment: Unlikely to be anything wrong with the motor, so rebuilding is the easier and cheaper solution. You unbolt the motor and all the parts are accessible, with no need to mess with the pipe connections. Looks fairly decent with some minor cosmetic rust on the cast housing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shallow well or "jet" pump, since it's on the surface. Appears to be Sta-Rite brand 1/2 HP, I can't make out the model number from that picture.

If there's one pipe into the well, it's a shallow well pump, (sometimes called an "internal jet" pump as it may have a jet, but it's not down in the well) if there are two pipes into the well it's a jet pump, where the pump pumps some water down into the well and a Venturi jet mechanism there brings up more water. If you have one of those and are facing replacement, just get a submersible deep well pump suited to your well rather than replacing with the same thing - they are an inefficient hold-over from an era when electric motors were less reliable.

It may need to be primed (filled with water) though USUALLY no prime means no water. Typically there's a plug on the top of the casting you open and pour water in until it overflows, then get the plug back in and turn the pump on.

It may have a worn out impeller, which is normally easily replaced (along with other parts that come as a "rebuild kit" for your specific pump make & model.) Depending on you, you can do that, or a well/pump company can do that for you. Any decent plumbing supply or hardware or farm supply store should be able to get you parts, or you can sort out what your pump model is and order online.

[image: Image from bellsupplyonline.com, no endorsement implied.]

Last one of these I worked on I'm pretty sure Agway had (or got on short notice) the parts we needed, and it took an hour or two (for us) to change.